# Most efficient way to ensure user owns document on update?

Tags: meteor

I'm using Meteor methods to update documents so I can share them easier and have more control. However i've ran into a problem with checking ownership.

How should I check to make sure the user calling the update method is the owner of the document? Currently i'm grabbing the document first then running the update.

Is there a better pattern to accomplish this?

```
Meteor.methods({

  'Listing.update': function(docId, data) {

    var doc = db.listings.findOne({_id: docId}) || {};

    if (doc.userId !== this.userId) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(504, "You don't own post");
    }

    // ensure data is the type we expect
    check(data, {
      title: String,
      desc: String
    });

    return db.listings.update(docId, {$set: data});
  }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the additional db call to fetch the original doc, just make the `userId` an additional criteria in the `update` selector.  If no doc exists with the correct `_id` and `userId` no update will be done.  `update` returns the number of docs updated so it will return 1 on success and 0 on failure.

like this:

```
'Listing.update': function(docId, data) {

  var self = this;
  check(data, {
    title: String,
    desc: String
  });

  if ( ! self.userId ) 
    throw new Meteor.Error(500, 'Must be logged in to update listing');

  res = db.listings.update({_id: docId, userId: self.userId}, {$set: data});

  if ( res === 0 )
    throw new Meteor.Error( 504, "You do not own a post with that id" );

  return res;
}
```

Also, if you use `findOne` to check a document's existence, use the fields option to limit what you return from the db.  Usually just `{fields: {_id:1}}`.

Comment: Thanks!! That will work really well. I don't necessarily need to know exactly that the ownership itself failed so a return count of 0 will do!